# 'sistema di regole congegnato' vs. 'sistema di regole congegnate'

Tags: grammar, word-choice, gender

> Credo queste dinamiche fossero chiarissime sia prima che durante la scrittura del sistema di regole all'uopo congegnato/e.

È preferibile usare 'congegnato' o 'congegnate' lì?

Answer (score 6):

Sono entrambi corretti: intendi dire che è il sistema a essere stato congegnato oppure le regole? Per fare un esempio più lampante, è come se dicessi “una pizza con i peperoni molto buona” rispetto a “una pizza con i peperoni molto buoni”: in un caso sottolinei la bontà della pizza nel complesso, nell'altro caso solo dei peperoni.